# Is there any scientific basis to this "catalytic converter" to treat hard water?

Tags: physics, chemistry, water

I came across this product called [Softer Water Conditioners](http://softerwaterconditioners.com/turbu-flow-technology/). It includes a lot of scientific sounding mumbo-jumbo to explain how it works, which *raises* my skepticism. Is there any scientific basis to this device, or this is just yet another pseudoscience?

> The SofterWater Conditioner technology is unique because it:
>
> - Prevents scale & also breaks down existing scale – without salts, chemicals or electricity
> - Provides an endless supply of ‘softened’ water without further cost or maintenance
>
> **How Does it Work?**
>
> Even though there are various ways to treat hard water using
>   sophisticated microprocessors and salt replacement technology the
>   science upon which the SofterWater Conditioner technology operates is
>   both simple and elegant. The technology is known as catalytic
>   conversion, and uses both chemistry and physics, without the addition
>   of chemicals to achieve amazing results. hard water
>
> Basically water is forced through a pipe with an alloy core.
>
> - The core has alloy discs along the internal pathway and each disc is
>     offset so that there is no direct route for the water to travel.
> - As the water travels through the alloy core areas of high (HP) and
>     low (LP) pressure are created along the chambers which causes
>     turbulence.
> - There is a definite electrochemical (galvanic, cathode anode)
>     reaction between the minerals in the water and the specially founded
>     alloy.
> - The turbulence creates a washing effect which prevents minerals from
>     building up on the alloy core and blocking the unit. The washing
>     effect also help with reducing the size of the minerals in the water.
> - The low pressure areas help release carbon dioxide and hydrogen
>     sulphide from the water reducing downstream corrosive problems.
>
> The result is that:
>
> - The zeta potential of the minerals is lowered (the electric charge), and
> - The crystalline structure of the minerals is changed to smaller nano colloid sized particles.
>
> Lowering the electrical charge of the minerals has the effect of
>   lowering the surface tension of the water.  This means the water is
>   'wetter' and it also means the cleaning power of the cold water is
>   increased to that of hot water!
>
> The bonding ability of the minerals is effectively neutralized and
>   breaks down large mineral crystals into tiny mineral particles and
>   prevents them from sticking to any surface to form scale.  This also
>   has the effect on the minerals  of remaining in suspension rather than
>   precipitating out onto the pipe and associated equipment.
>
> Simply, the SofterWater Conditioner technology changes the molecular
>   structure of the mineral crystals in hard water.  The minerals become
>   tiny particles and instead of clumping together and attaching to
>   surfaces they pass straight through.  Essentially the water treatment
>   both prevents and cures scale build up.

Comment: It looks like snake oil. They mention a catalyst but don't say what the chemical reaction is .

Comment: It's utter BS.  Water hardness is caused by minerals dissolved in the water.  (Note, they are not "crystals" or "particles".)

Comment: "nano colloid sized particles" is technobabble. A colloidal mixture is defined by its particles being 1..1000 nm. So, every colloidal mixture is, taken literally, "nano sized". But it's still technobabble.

Comment: Well at least it lowers the zeta potential.